# Citing the same source twice in a row, in a business document

Tags: citation

In a business document for work, I'm citing data from a market research paper (Gartner). I cite data from the same source 3 times across 2 paragraphs. Keep in mind this is not an academic paper. Is it enough that I refer to the source (Gartner) after the first mention, or do I need to continuously specify the specific paper its from? I'd like to know the official best-practice. In this case, there are no other papers cited from that source.

Example:
"According to Gartner's 2021 Magic Quadrant on Widgets, Acme Inc was the 2021 market leader, with an $XM share of the market. The growth of Acme's revenue exceeded Y% over the past 5 years. This may reflect the increasing use of widgets when shoveling snow.
Data from Gartner suggests the total market size of widgets is $XB globally in 2021."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There isn't an official guide on how to cite sources in business documents. You can see if your employer has a style guide, check out other documents, or ask someone (or submit your document for review and see if anyone changes it). We can't judge if a given solution is ambiguous or likely to confuse people, which should be your main principles.

Comment: The reason to specify page numbers and publishing dates is to allow your reader to check your sources. Would your readers ever need that? In business or academia, your reader can get from one sentence to the next on the same citation.